# How to find url of exposed service in kubernetes dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes

Have kubernetes service running and dashboard running. Where is the URL? How to check it from the dashboard?

Comment: You will see services under 'discovery and load balancing' https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/27387957ff08948103973a61a1add0f46acce9d3/032db/images/docs/ui-dashboard-service-list.png Is that what you mean? Or how to access dashboard (if so see https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-install-the-kubernetes-dashboard)

Comment: Thanks, and I guess if there are no external endpoints that means nothing can see anything and things did not work?

Comment: There are different ways of exposing services so it depends on the service type. See https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0